# How to reuse angular components from different folders of the project?

Tags: angular, angular-module

I have an Angular project where the previous developers have copy / pasted components.

In this project mobile view is completely different from the desktop view, except some components and those components which could be reused, they are exactly copy/pasted by the developers. And even the '.ts' files of the different template views are also copy/pasted which could be reused.

Now I have two question

1. If I make a shared module and reuse that module in both the desktop
   and mobile folder does it have any impact on the speed / performance
   of the application as there are more than 50 components which needs
   to be done ?
2. Is it a standard to copy/paste code rather to reuse those
   components.?

**You can get a clear picture of my question by seeing the attached image link below.**
https://ibb.co/DgT4rwh

Comment: Vitalii Bobrov's answer is the correct way to do it when re-using modules and components across projects. But from that screenshot it looks like they might be copying/pasting inside the *same* project. You should always consolidate and reuse modules/components/services. The only impact it will have on speed will be to lower your application's overall size (fewer components = less code) and increase initial load time as a result. And as for #2, it is never standard to copy/paste code and that is a hallmark of an inexperienced developer in my experience.

Comment: Hi @Dean. I found your answer to be perfect. Can you post this comment as an answer so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vitalii Bobrov's answer is the correct way to do it when re-using modules and components across projects. But from that screenshot it looks like they might be copying/pasting inside the same project. You should always consolidate and reuse modules/components/services. The only impact it will have on speed will be to lower your application's overall size (fewer components = less code) and increase initial load time as a result. And as for #2, it is never standard to copy/paste code and that is a hallmark of an inexperienced developer in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

It is not ok to copy/paste components, you should use shared modules or libraries for that, see docs for the reference:

https://next.angular.io/guide/file-structure

https://next.angular.io/guide/libraries

https://next.angular.io/guide/styleguide

Answer (score 0):

We should follow DRY principle of coding. You should create a shared module containing the duplicate components , which will be used by other modules.